# Firebase API and Vue.JS get multiple elements by specific attributes value

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vue.js, promise

How to get all elements in Firebase (child) which has the same category ID ?

```
getbyCateg: function(myCateg) {
      var items = [];
      FireBase.database().ref('product')
          .orderByChild('category')
          .equalTo(myCateg)
          .once("value", function(snapshot) {
              var key;
              snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
                  key = childSnapshot.key;
                  return true;
              });
              if (key) {
                  items.push(FireBase.database().ref('product').child(key).toString());
              } else {
                  console.log("There is nothing of this category");
              }
          });
      return (items);
```

.once allow to access the first element which has the good category ID, but what about the others ? I would like to create an array of all of these elements.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing your data structure, I am not sure what is your problem really. But maybe is this everything, you need:

```
getbyCateg: function(myCateg) {
  var items = [];
  FireBase.database().ref('product')
    .orderByChild('category')
    .equalTo(myCateg)
    .once("value", function(snapshot) {
      snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
        key = childSnapshot.key;
        if (key) {
          // also, try this items.push(key.toString()) instead of next line
          items.push(FireBase.database().ref('product').child(key).toString());
        } else {
          console.log("There is nothing of this category");
        }
      });
    });
  return (items);
}
```